# Access iCloud emails on an Android without Mac or iPhone

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id

I want to access my iCloud emails on my Android phone.

- Using a browser doesn't work; iCloud.com just says: **Your browser is not currently supported**. (Tested with Firefox, Microsoft Edge and Chrome).
- Using a regular Mail app requires an application specific password, which in turn requires Two-Factor authentication. But I don't have a compatible device (iPhone, Mac, etc.) for enabling Two-Factor authentication.

How can I access my iCloud email (and calendar, if possible)?

Comment: If you don't have access to an Apple device, how are you planning to receive the Two-Factor Authentication code?

Comment: Use of iCloud without any Apple device is probably not really supported by Apple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get [iCloud website](https://www.icloud.com) to work fine by accessing the Desktop site in any of the modern mobile browsers.

I tried it using the current latest version of Google Chrome for Android (70.0.3538.80). It is preferred as it is pre-installed on most Android devices and is regularly updated.

Once you load the [iCloud website](https://www.icloud.com), a message is shown stating Your browser is not currently supported.

[image]

Simply tap on the options button shown towards the top right and tap on **Desktop Site** item to request the Desktop version of the website.

[image] [image]

iCloud website now loads and you can login just like you do on a Desktop browser.

[image]

When logging-in for the first time on your Android device, you'll need to get the six-digit, Two-Factor Authentication code from any one of your trusted device. After successfully entering it, you can choose to trust the browser, and you will not be asked for a verification code the next time you sign in.

[image] [image]

Voila!, iCloud website just loads fine.

[image]

Accessing Mail and Calendar apps on iCloud website, running on Google Chrome for Android.

[image] [image]

Better usability in landscape mode.

[image] [image]

You mentioned that you don't have access to your Mac/iPhone. You'll still need a way to get the Two-Factor authentication code which is generated when attempting login.

Once you manage to get the Two-Factor Authentication code, you can choose to trust the browser and you won't be needing the same in future.

Also, while logging out, do note to leave the checkmark against **Remember me on this browser, so I don't have to verify my identity next time** enabled. That way, you won't be required to enter the Two-Factor Authentication code again.

[image]

Comment: I had to remove the `/unsupported_mobile/` part after switching to desktop site. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to request the desktop site of icloud.com within your Android browser (don‘t know too much about Android, but there should be an option for that). If this doesn‘t work, visit a friend with a PC/Mac/Linux machine, an Internet cafe, etc to log in to iCloud.com once and generate the password needed. Don‘t forget to do this in private mode so any login details get deleted afterwards.

Comment: that displays the same `Your browser is not currently supported` message, but as a desktop site.

Comment: i cannot generate the application specific password, because that needs two-factor authentication, which I can't enable.

Comment: If you don‘t have 2FA enabled what do you need an application specific password for?